# "Wake On Lan"-Cable - 3-Pin Connector type name

Tags: cable, wake-on-lan, connector

I am trying to find the name of the connector (company and connector type name) displayed below:

[image]

- This connector type was often used on PCI Network interface cards.

Comment: You may find better assistance with questions like these on Stack's Electrical Engineering site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These connectors are: **AMP CT Series 2.0mm**.

Answer (score 0):

The type of connector is a crimp socket housing typically manufactured by Molex (2.00mm Microlatch).

One [producer of such cables](https://www.crystalfontz.com/product/wrpwry14-serial-atx-power-cable) identifies the specific part numbers as 51065-0300 (housing) and 50212-8100 (crimp socket).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Looking closely, the Microlatch series however does not seem to match (no round pins, and no latch on the housing located near the second pin). But your response I got me looking one more time, and I think I finally found a match: The AMP CT Series 2.0mm.  For example: 292161-3 AMP CT, PCB Mount Header, Vertical, Wire-to-Board, 3 Position, 2mm.